# Set the WinSpy++ Control id at a C# window

Tags: c#

I have a little C# program with TextBox and other components. When I examing the TextBox (or other) components with WinSpy++, I get a Control ID which I cannot find at my C# source code. For example - see screenshots: When I examine the TextBox field with number 5, WinSpy++ detects the Control ID 000209AA.

[image: C# test program]

[image: WinSpy TextBox detection]

How identifies WinSpy the Control ID? Is there any possibility to set the Control ID at the C# source code?

Cheers,
Achim

Comment: This is an XY question.  You are simply seeing the Handle value back.  Winforms uses it to ensure that every control has a unique ID, tinkering with it is liable to break something.  The AccessibleName property was meant to help anybody find that textbox back.

Answer (score 0):

`GetDlgCtrlID` from user32.dll will provide the control ID given the window handle (ie, Control.Handle). Very simple form to demonstrate:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int GetDlgCtrlID(IntPtr hwnd);

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Control ID: " + GetDlgCtrlID(textBox1.Handle));
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure that there's any way to *set* the control ID - I suspect the control ID is set automatically by Windows Forms somehow in the form construction. But being able to retrieve it should be sufficient for most applications (eg direct use of PostMessage/SendMessage from Windows API.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I want to set the control ID myself. I think there is a way to handle this. When I start the Windows calculator several times, all GUI components have constant control ID. But when I start my little C# application for several times, I got always a different control id from aa GUI components.

Comment: I don't believe that's possible. From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996405.aspx:

"Traditionally, the identifier for UI was the control ID. This was a locale-independent solution, which persisted across multiple instances of the form, and was unique over 90 percent of the time. However, in Windows Forms, the control ID is a mirror image of the HWND for that particular control. Thus, the control ID is different every time you launch the form, so you cannot use this as your UI identifier."

The constant control ID apps are likely MFC or raw WinAPI applications, not Windows Forms.